# Correct normalizer syntax for normalizing JSON

Tags: json, redux, react-redux, normalizr

I'm trying to use `normalizer` to normalize some JSON. My JSON looks like

```
  total: 8029,
  items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Jacket1',
      sku: '123',
      upc: '1',
      price: '99.99',
      images: ['url1', 'url2'],
      category: 'clothing',
      thumbnail:
        'https://cdn.zeplin.io/5969021e44c5978909d5278b/assets/1CE5FF07-E70F-4413-85BF-49C08AA559DE.png',
    }, ...
```

and from the examples, I thought this might work

```
  const itemSchema = new schema.Entity('items')
  const itemsSchema = new schema.Entity('result', {
    items: [itemSchema],
  })

  const foo = normalize(fakeDatabase, itemsSchema)
```

But I end up with one result that is undefined, and that undefined value has some funky stuff in it.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't believe `itemsSchema` is necessary. Try `normalize(fakeDatabase, { items: [itemSchema] })`

Comment: thanks for replying. unfortunately, it did not work. my items array returned as an array of numbers. I think I'll just work around this with `lodash`

Comment: @OrB your answer was actually correct. Sorry about that. If you add that answer, i'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe `itemsSchema` is necessary. Try either:

```
normalize(fakeDatabase, { items: new schema.Array(itemSchema) })
```

or

```
normalize(fakeDatabase, { items: [itemSchema] })
```